# Calculate $\sum^{\infty}_{r=1} \frac{8}{(2r-1)\sqrt{(2r+3)(2r+5)}+\sqrt{(2r+1)(2r-1)}(2r+3)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

If $\sum^{\infty}_{r=1} \frac{8}{(2r-1)\sqrt{(2r+3)(2r+5)}+\sqrt{(2r+1)(2r-1)}(2r+3)}=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}}-\sqrt{c}$, where $a$ and $c$ are coprime numbers, then the value of $a+\frac{c}{4}$ is
(1) 3
(2) 5
(3) 8
(4) 4

I'm completely lost here, some pointers would be nice.

I tried putting it into Wolfram Alpha to see if it could get a partial sum formula, but that didn't seem to work.

And putting in the entire series itself just gave me a decimal approximation (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: That's the thing - I haven’t really done much. I tried evaluating up to r=4, but couldn't really find any patterns to work with.

Comment: Is this problem you invented or it's a homework assignment in your class?  is it a problem you teacher made up and assigned it to your class as a bonus question?

Comment: I'd say it best fits under the category of a "bonus" question - we've learned techniques to solve infinite series (finding partial sum formulas and taking the limit to infinity, telescoping, etc.) and this is supposed to be a more 'abstract' application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: Use telescoping series. Multiply numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{\frac{2r+5}{2r+3}}-\sqrt{\frac{2r+1}{2r-1}}$, to get final simplified expression for $t_{r}$ as under.

$$\begin{aligned}t_{r}&=\frac{8}{(2r-1)(2r+3)\left[\sqrt{\frac{2r+5}{2r+3}}+\sqrt{\frac{2r+1}{2r-1}}\right]} \\ &= \sqrt{\frac{2r+1}{2r-1}}-\sqrt{\frac{2r+5}{2r+3}}\end{aligned}$$

Now define $a_{r}=\sqrt{\frac{2r+1}{2r-1}}$, so that $t_{r}=a_{r}-a_{r+2}$. The sum would be $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}(a_{r}-a_{r+2})=a_{1}+a_{2}-2a_{\infty}$. Since $a_{\infty}\to 1$, $a_{1}=\sqrt{3}$ and $a_{2}=\sqrt{5/3}$. So the answer seems to be $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}}-\sqrt{4}\approx 1.01808$.

Comment: $t_r =a_r-a_{r+2}$. Note that according to the exercise, the sum should contain $\sqrt {\frac{5}{3}}$ and we are looking for those numbers $a$ and $c$. The correct value should be $
\sqrt 3  + \sqrt {\frac{5}{3}}  - \sqrt 4$.

Comment: @Gary Thanks for pointing out. I'll edit it out.

Comment: So $a=3$, $c=4$ and hence $a+\frac{c}{4}=4$, i.e., $(4)$ is the correct choice.

Comment: Thank you so much!